# How to Understand this #define in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm currently reading "The C puzzle book" and I found a #define that I would like to understand how it works.

```
#define PRINT(int) printf(#int " = %d\n", int)
```

I've never seen something like #int before so I wrote a small program to try the above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINT(int) printf(#int " = %d\n", int)
int main()
{
    PRINT(10);
}

Result: 10 = 10
```

How does the preprocessor interpret #int in this case and where can I read more about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Using `#` inside C macros is called "*Stringification*" and you can read more about it here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` *stringizing operator* expands the name to a quoted string, so here:

```
printf(#int " = %d\n", int)
```

to

```
printf("10" " = %d\n", 10);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf("10 = %d\n", 10);
```

In the example the `int` parameter name in the macro definition is a little bit confusing and should be replaced by something better.